# ¿como aplicar una correcta divicion en capas del codigo?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, entity-framework-6

Estaba viendo este video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lAKJL3Crvso&list=WL&index=4&t=218s , y especificamente en el minuto 2:35 comienza a hablar sobre lo que deberia en cada capa (si se usa las 3 clasicas de **datos, negocio y presentacion**), donde dice que la "logica del negocio" debe ser aplicada en la capa de negocio, y me genero duda despues de eso de que se consideraria correcto y que no en especifico poner en cada capa con el fin de hacer un codigo mas ordenado y escalable.

En mi **capa de datos** no hago mucho realmente porque por el momento utilizo entity framework que se encarga de generar las tablas virtuales de mi base de datos y realizar las conexiones logicas.

En la **capa de negocio** puse una clase por cada tabla en mi base de datos para aplicarle **CRUD**, tomando los objetos que me genera el entity en la capa de datos que previamente referencie, ademas de 2 clases mas, una que se encarga de generar los back up de mi base de datos y otra que se encarga de comrprobar si hay impresoras conectadas.

Finalmente en mi **capa de presentacion** tengo lo relacionado a la interfaz grafica, pero no se si hay codigo que no le corresponde a esa capa, como lo puede ser el de preparar lo que la impresora va a imprimir para luego imprimirlo (todo en esa capa).

Ejemplo de codigo en mi **capa de presentacion** (metodo de imprimir):

```
string InformacionDelError = string.Empty;

            ClsInformacionesRestaurantes InformacionesRestaurantes = new ClsInformacionesRestaurantes();
            InformacionRestaurante BuscarDatosRestaurante = InformacionesRestaurantes.LeerPorNumero(1, ref InformacionDelError);

            Font FuenteCuerpo = new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);
            Font FuenteTituloCuerpo = new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point);
            Font FuenteEncabezadoPie = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point);
            Font FuenteEncabezadoPieSimple = new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point);
            Font FuenteNombreRestaurante = new Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point);
            SolidBrush Pincel = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

            float AlturaFuente = FuenteCuerpo.GetHeight();
            int ComienzoX = 5;
            int ComienzoY = 0;
            int Compensar = 40;
            int SubCompensar = 3;

            if (BuscarDatosRestaurante != null)
            {
                int PosicionX = 10;

                if (BuscarDatosRestaurante.Nombre.Length >= 11 && BuscarDatosRestaurante.Nombre.Length < 16)
                {
                    FuenteNombreRestaurante = new Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point);
                }
                else if (BuscarDatosRestaurante.Nombre.Length >= 16)
                {
                    FuenteNombreRestaurante = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point);
                }

                switch (BuscarDatosRestaurante.Nombre.Length)
                {
                    case 3: PosicionX = 63; break;
                    case 4: PosicionX = 53; break;
                    case 5: PosicionX = 48; break;
                    case 6: PosicionX = 36; break;
                    case 7: PosicionX = 27; break;
                    case 8: PosicionX = 18; break;
                    case 9: PosicionX = 10; break;
                    case 10: PosicionX = 5; break;
                    case 11: PosicionX = 20; break;
                    case 12: PosicionX = 18; break;
                    case 13: PosicionX = 14; break;
                    case 14: PosicionX = 12; break;
                    case 15: PosicionX = 10; break;
                    case 16: PosicionX = 20; break;
                    case 17: PosicionX = 18; break;
                    case 18: PosicionX = 16; break;
                    case 19: PosicionX = 14; break;
                    case 20: PosicionX = 12; break;
                }

                e.Graphics.DrawString(BuscarDatosRestaurante.Nombre, FuenteNombreRestaurante, Pincel, PosicionX, ComienzoY);

                if (BuscarDatosRestaurante.Eslogan != null)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString($"  {BuscarDatosRestaurante.Eslogan}", FuenteEncabezadoPie, Pincel, ComienzoX, ComienzoY + FuenteNombreRestaurante.GetHeight());
                    Compensar += (int)AlturaFuente + SubCompensar;
                }
            }// CONTINUA
```

Para no hacer largo el post, en la de negocio es basicamente sentencias como estas (este metodo es el READ del CRUD, en donde `EstadoCaja` es un objeto de la capa de datos):

```
    public List<EstadoCaja> LeerListado(ref string _InformacionDelError)
    {
        using (BDRestauranteEntities BBDD = new BDRestauranteEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                return BBDD.EstadoCaja.ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception Error)
            {
                _InformacionDelError = $"Ocurrio un error inesperado al intentar listar los datos: {Error.Message}";
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veras una cosa que igual no te contó el video es que la Arquitectura de 3-Capas no es mas que una arquitectura de N-Capas con un uso recurrente en informatica.

En principio podrías realizar cualquier arquitectura con varias capas que quisieras como si tienes dos!!

Con lo que te tienes que quedar y con esto remarco es que las capas disminuyen la cohesión y las dependencias, entre diferentes implementaciones.

Si tu quieres eliminar la capa de negocio no es ningún crimen... sobretodo siendo una aplicación pequeña y CRUD. Pero al añadir funcionalidad tendrás problemas de relaciones entre vistas, por que una vista tiene implementado una cosa y otra necesita otra cosa pero otra que no te acordabas lo tenia implementado...

Las Arquitecturas están diseñadas para la incrementalidad del codigo con sentido, así que deberias preguntarte si en algún momento del ciclo de vida de tu aplicación tu negocio va a ser esencial para el correcto funcionamiento de tu programa.

Espero que con esto te haya solucionado un poco tu lio. te dejo una referencia a la arquitectura de N-Capas.

http://iutll-abdd.blogspot.com/2012/05/arquitectura-de-n-capas.html

PD: Aprender estas cosas vienen muy bien y se usa en todos los lenguajes con clases y interfaces. Yo por ejemplo programo en Java y TypeScript!! Tambien te recomiendo leer sobre Arquitectura orientada al dominio, es si no es una arquitectura es un conjunto de Patrones de diseño, pero es muy intersante.

Saludos!

Comment: Le dare un vistazo a la "Arquitectura orientada al dominio", para ver si me es util en futuros proyectos. Lo de las capas ahora me quedo mas claro.

Comment: Lo que tenia "miedo o dudas", era si estaba implementando mal las reglas de esta arquitectura, poniendo algo en la capa de presentacion que en realidad era para la de negocio. Por ejemplo, ese codigo de impresion ¿deberia ser llamado desde la capa de presentacion a una clase de la capa de negocio?, u otro ejemplo, es que la validacion de que un plato ya este cocinado ¿la deberia hacer en alguna clase de esta capa intermedia? (y no llamando a la de negocio y viendo que me devolvio para despues hacer las validaciones en la de presentacion).

Comment: No me quedo claro si en el video al decir "Las reglas que deben cumplirse", se referia a lo que se indica en el codigo de LinQ para obtener un dato, o si se referia a hacer en esta capa lo que puse en el comentario de arriba.

Comment: En la capa de presentación solo debes manipular la interacción en la comunicación, en el caso de interfaces graficas los elementos o páginas web y en el caso de que sea comunicación Maquina-Maquina ( Rest, SOAP ), la comunicación y la envoltura de los datos. La manipulación de los datos del modelo de la aplicación siempre suele ser misión del negocio y la capa de datos solo tendría la misión de comunicarse con la base de datos, nada mas.